# How do I do "eval" on a string containing a function

Tags: javascript, eval

In the following example, I would expect `b` and `c = eval(a)` to contain the same function, one that always returns true. However, `a` does not get evaluated, it rather throws a syntax error:
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Function statements require a function name`. However, if if name the function, `c` contains `undefined`.

```
var a = "function() { return true }";

var b = function() { return true };

var c = eval(a);

console.log(b,c);
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the code you're feeding into `eval` is being evaluated where a statement is expected, but the code you have after `var b =` is being evaluated as an expression. When the parser is expecting a statement, the `function` keyword starts a function *declaration*, which requires a name. But where an expression is expected, the `function` keyword starts a function *expression*, in which a name is optional.

To make your `eval` work on an expression instead, surround the code with `(` and `)`:

```js
var a = "function() { return true }";

var b = function() { return true };

var c = eval("(" + a + ")");
// −−−−−−−−−−^^^^^−−−^^^^^

console.log(b,c);
```

---

**Warning**: Be very careful using `eval` and avoid using it if possible. Its purpose is to execute arbitrary code from strings. If you use it, you **must** trust that the source of that string is trustworthy. Never take user input from user A and then `eval` it in a session for user B unless user B is fully aware of what's going on (for instance, as with the Stack Snippet above — I'm user A, you're user B; presumably if you click the Run button, you realize code will get run). In fact, when dealing with non-programmers, don't even eval code from user A in user A's session. :-)

Comment: thank you - in this very case the evil eval is legacy and I can't do nothing about it.